# MySQL InnoDB - GROUP BY on many items

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, query-optimization

I've got a table that has `id`, `date`, `ad_id`, `ad_network`, `ad_event` columns.
In my database there are millions of distinct `ad_id` each has a few events associated with them.
When I try to use `GROUP BY` on the `ad_id` to count each event it takes so long there is 503 error.

I need to count distinct `AdClickThru` and `AdImpression` so that I can calculate the CTR.
The problem is that one user can click many times, so I must count only one `AdClickThru`.

The query is below:

```
SELECT
    `ad_network`,
    `ad_id`,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `ad_event` = "AdImpression" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AdImpression,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `ad_event` = "AdClickThru" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AdClickThru
FROM `ads`
WHERE 1
    AND `ad_event` IN ("AdImpression", "AdClickThru")
    AND SUBSTR(`date`, 1, 7) = "2020-08"
GROUP BY `ad_id`
```

I have indexes on `ad_id` and `ad_event + date` but it does not help much.

How can I optimize this query?
The database will grow to billions of entries and more.

@edit

Forgot to mention that the code above is inner part of outer query:

```
    SELECT
        `ad_network`,
        SUM(`AdImpression`) as cnt_AdImpression,
        SUM(`AdClickThru`) as cnt_AdClickThru,
        100 * SUM(`AdClickThru`) / SUM(`AdImpression`) as ctr
    FROM (
        SELECT
            `ad_network`,
            `ad_id`,
            SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `ad_event` = "AdImpression" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AdImpression,
            SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `ad_event` = "AdClickThru" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AdClickThru
        FROM `ads`
        WHERE 1
            AND `ad_event` IN ("AdImpression", "AdClickThru")
            AND SUBSTR(`date`, 1, 7) = "2020-08" -- better performance
        GROUP BY `ad_id`
    ) a
    GROUP BY `ad_network`
    ORDER BY ctr DESC
```

Comment: *`SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN {some expression} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`* - it may be 0 or 1 only.

Comment: *How can I optimize this query?* ```CREATE INDEX idx ON ads (ad_id, ad_network, `date`, ad_event)``` and replace `AND SUBSTR(`date`, 1, 7) = "2020-08"` with two unequations.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Further, in addition to the above, questions about query optimisation also require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for 2 separate aggregations in the main query and the subquery.
You want to count the distinct `ad_id`s for each of the 2 cases:

```
SELECT ad_network,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ad_event = 'AdImpression' THEN ad_id END) AS cnt_AdImpression,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ad_event = 'AdClickThru' THEN ad_id END) AS cnt_AdClickThru,
       100 * 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ad_event = 'AdClickThru' THEN ad_id END) / 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ad_event = 'AdImpression' THEN ad_id END) AS ctr
FROM ads
WHERE ad_event IN ('AdImpression', 'AdClickThru') AND SUBSTR(date, 1, 7) = '2020-08'
GROUP BY ad_network
ORDER BY ctr DESC
```

The problem here is that you have to repeat the expressions for `cnt_AdImpression` and `cnt_AdClickThru`.
You can calculate these expressions in a subquery:

```
SELECT ad_network, cnt_AdImpression, cnt_AdClickThru,
       100 * cnt_AdClickThru / cnt_AdImpression AS ctr
FROM (
  SELECT ad_network,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ad_event = 'AdImpression' THEN ad_id END) AS cnt_AdImpression,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ad_event = 'AdClickThru' THEN ad_id END) AS cnt_AdClickThru
  FROM ads
  WHERE ad_event IN ('AdImpression', 'AdClickThru') AND SUBSTR(date, 1, 7) = '2020-08'
  GROUP BY ad_network
) t
ORDER BY ctr DESC
```

Comment: Your answer is so much better than what I came up with. It does not throw 503 error when I run it so it must be much faster. Do you have any idea why `SUBSTR(date, 1, 7) = '2020-08'` is faster than `date >= '2020-08-01' AND date < '2020-09-01'`?

Comment: The use of a function like SUBSTR() shouldn't be faster than a straight comparison on dates. But if no indexes are used it is possible.

Comment: I have these indexes: primary on `id`, next is on `ad_id`, and the last one on `date + ad_event`

Comment: If there is an index on `date + ad_event` it *could* be used. If it is not used then drop it and try also with an index on `(ad_event, date)`.

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE ads ADD INDEX ad_event_date (ad_event, date);` does not use the key either. It appears in `possible_keys` but `keys` is `null` in `EXPLAIN ...` statement

Comment: Add: `FORCE INDEX (ad_event_date )` before the WHERE clause and see if there is any difference.

Comment: It's more than 2 times slower than without `FORCE INDEX`. The `date` field is of type `char(10)`.

Comment: So there is a reason that the optimizer does not use any index, maybe because a full table scan is better.

Comment: The old query took more than 60 seconds (503 error), the new query takes about 5 seconds. I have mere 2.5 million entries and I expect to have 30 million entries per month. Is there no other way to speed it up?

Comment: You can only experiment with variations of the code. For example remove `ad_event IN ('AdImpression', 'AdClickThru')` from the WHERE clause and use `date >= '2020-08-01' AND date <  '2020-09-01'` only with an index on `date`. If it speeds up add a HAVING clause: `HAVING AdImpression > 0 OR AdClickThru > 0` and check again. Things like that.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that one user can click many times, so I must count only one AdClickThru.

Then use `MAX()`, not `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. This gives the same result as your expression, and is much more efficient. I would also recommend rewriting the date filter so it is index-friendly:

```
SELECT
    `ad_network`,
    `ad_id`,
    MAX(`ad_event` = 'AdImpression') as AdImpression,
    MAX(`ad_event` = 'AdClickThru') as AdClickThru
FROM `ads`
WHERE 1
    AND `ad_event` IN ('AdImpression', 'AdClickThru')
    AND `date` >= '2020-08-01'
    AND `date` <  '2020-09-01'
GROUP BY `ad_id`
```

Notes:

- the presence of `ad_network` in the `select` clause is hitching me: if there are several values per `ad_id`, it is undefined which will be picked. Either put this column in the `group by` clause as well, or use an aggregate function in the `sélect` clause (such as `MAX(ad_network)` - or if you are ok with an arbitrary value, then be explicit about it with `any_value()`
- use single quotes for literal strings rather than double quotes (this is the SQL standard)

Comment: I'm using `SUM()` and not `COUNT()` would it still be equiwalent? Also please look at my edit, maybe it can put some light on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ajin: yes, it is equivalent (that’s a typo from me). Note that my answer addresses the original version of your question.

Comment: I would also add an explanation why you changed the date filter (your solution can use index, the OP's cannot)